# How to get the average percentage of a column with condition from text data

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

I start with text data from a Google Sheet like this:

```
   A        B     
1  Subject1 Text1 
2  Subject2 Text2 
3  Subject1 Text3 
4  Subject1 Text3 
5  Subject1 Text2
```

What I want is to get the average in percent form of column B but only for Subject1 rows.

The text can be translated in numbers like this:

- Text1 = 0
- Text2 = 0.5
- Text3 = 1

The formula or script can be summarized like this:

```
(Text1=0;Text3=1;Text3=1;Text2=0.5) AND (AVERAGE of B column but only for Subject1 rows in A column) = 0.625 AND (to PERCENT)
```

Finally, I get the end result: **63%**

I tried several formulas and Apps Script but got errors and don't know enough JavaScript. Do you know how to get this end result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`=AVERAGE(FILTER(IFERROR(SWITCH(B:B,"Text1",0,"Text2",0.5,"Text3",1)),A:A="Subject1"))`

Just format the cell to percentage (**Format > Number > Percent** -or- **Format > Number > More Formats > Custom number format >** *0%*).

Comment: Thank you, it's working with this formula but only after I changed my regional parameters for those of USA and tick the case to use English functions only. Those options are in File menu, Spreadsheet settings.

Comment: If you want to keep your original location settings, try just changing every comma in the formula to a semicolon.